# Laravel Mix unknown option '--hide-modules' error

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

When I try to compile React component with Laravel Mix in my Laravel project it raises error 2 lifecycle.

```
E:\MY PROJECTS\Samriddhi Institute> npm run dev
```

> @ dev E:\MY PROJECTS\Samriddhi Institute
> npm run development
>
> @ development E:\MY PROJECTS\Samriddhi Institute
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/
> setup/webpack.config.js
>
> [webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--hide-modules' [webpack-cli] Run
> 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options npm ERR! code
> ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2 npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=no de_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js` npm ERR! Exit status 2
> npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script. npm ERR! This is
> probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
> output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\RADHESHYAM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-17T05_52_36_957Z-debug.log
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2 npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development` npm ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the @
> dev script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
> likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\RADHESHYAM\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-17T05_52_37_148Z-debug.log
> PS E:\MY PROJECTS\Samriddhi Institute>"

[image: Error shown on image]

Answer (score 86):

**Update Laravel Mix**

```
npm install --save-dev laravel-mix@latest
```

**Update Your NPM Scripts**

If your build throws an error such as `Unknown argument: --hide-modules`, the scripts section of your package.json file will need to be updated. The Webpack 5 CLI removed a number of options that your NPM scripts was likely referencing.

While you're at it, go ahead and switch over to the new Mix CLI.

**Before**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

**After**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,i can implement your suggestion and also remove all node modules ,package.lock file and reinstall everything now it's working fine  thanks lot again

Comment: after upgrading the laravel mix to the latest, my prod build CSS is excluding almost all the CSS and outputting a very few styles. Any thoughts on where I can start debugging for that issue?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70350578/npm-run-prod-is-breaking-the-site

Comment: I faced the same problem, I used to undo changes(discard using vs-code source control) to my app.css after every build. It saved me.

Comment: this solution is not working!

Comment: This worked for me. In addition, just make sure that you're using node v16

Comment: This totally worked. Thank you so much for posting this.

Comment: rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json and do that steps

Answer (score 16):

I had this issue and solved it by downgrading laravel-mix to

`"laravel-mix": "^5.0.9"`

then running:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove --hide-modules from your package.json and than run npm run dev it will run without erros.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced similar error working on a laravel project on ubuntu 22.04 with the following library versions:

```
laravel-mix: 6.0.49,

npm version: 8.19.4

node: 16.20.2
```

I solved the error by editing `package.json` file as shown:

*Before----------------:*

```
"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
"watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
"hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"prod": "npm run production",
"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
```

*After----------------:*

```
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
"watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
"hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"prod": "npm run production",
"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
```

Note: I removed the `--hide-modules`

And it worked!

Answer (score -2):

In my case i had to switch to *node version* **14** as i was on **18**.
My steps.

(1) Check current node version.

```
nvm list # -->v18.4
```

(2) Switched to node 14.

```
nvm use 14.19
```

(3) Installed again

```
npm install
```

(4) Run dev

```
npm run dev
```

It worked.